# Using semantic ontologies to convert a Relational Database to RDF

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, ontology, virtuoso

I have been lately trying to describe a given RDB(Relational Database) with specific semantic ontologies, using Virtuoso. The ontologies that i want to use are: dc,foaf,dct,bibo,cito(I am new to this so I didnt quite understand if dc and dct are the same thing). 
I have been following this tutorial on how to do this:
http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/whitepapers/relational%20rdf%20views%20mapping.html

My problem is that in this tutorial classes are created from zero while I need to use existing ones. Unfortunately I am not allowed to post the links of the ontologies too.
In particular I want to describe:

#### An "author" table(a published paper author) that has the following columns:

AuthorID, AuthorName, AuthorMiddleName, AuthorSurname, AuthorURL, AuthorEmail, Department

#### A "Keywords" table(publication's keywords) with the columns:

PublicationID, Keyword(type of string), KeywordOrder(type of Integer),

#### A "Publications" table with the columns:

PublicationID, PublicationTitle, MediaType(type of string), PublicationType(Integer), MediaTitle, MediaPublisher, MediaEditors, MediaVolInfo, PublicationYear, PublicationNoOfPages, PublicationPagesInMedium, PublicationFileName, PublicationComments, PublicationRelatedURL, PublicationRelatedURLText, PublicationLocation, PublicationPubURL, DisplayOnMLKD(type of Integer), DisplayOnISKP(type of Integer), DisplayOnWeb(type of Integer)

#### A "References" table (publication's references) with the columns:

RefID, RefPaperID, RefDetails, RefYear

#### A "Rights" table (publication's rights) with the columns:

PublicationID, AuthorID, AuthorOrder

I tried doing some of this work but I think I might have some problems.
For example, I am currently trying to express the "Publications" table and in my file I have the following:

```
@prefix dc:      <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix db:      <http://lpis.csd.auth.gr/> .
@prefix foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix cito:    <http://purl.org/net/cito/> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix dct:     <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix bibo:    <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix map:     <http://lpis.csd.auth.gr#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix vocab:   <http://localhost:2020/vocab/resource/> .
@prefix atr: <http://localhost:8890/rdfv_pt/schemas/authors#> .
@prefix kwrd: <http://localhost:8890/rdfv_pt/schemas/keywords#> .
@prefix pub: <http://localhost:8890/rdfv_pt/schemas/publications#> .
@prefix ref: <http://localhost:8890/rdfv_pt/schemas/references#> .
@prefix rig: http://localhost:8890/rdfv_pt/schemas/rights#> .

pub:Publication a rdfs:Class 
rdfs:label "Publication" ;
rdfs:comment "Publication Class" .

pub:PublicationID a dc:identifier .

pub:PublicationTitle a dc:title .

pub:MediaType a rdf:Property ;
rdfs:domain pub:Publication;
rdfs:range xsd:string ;
rdfs:label "Media type" .
```

#### Question 1:

So this is just a fragment but my question here is how do I express that the "Publication" is a class of an existing ontology? As you can see above I am defining from zero the class "Publication".

#### Question 2(more important):

As you can see in the tutorial, somehow the tables that were imported in the virtuoso tool were mapped to a specific URL. However, I wasn't able to find the URL to each table that I imported to virtuoso and I just put some placeholder URLs (These are the localhost URLs). How can i find out the URL to each of the tables that I imported to virtuoso?

PS. Any information at all would be extremely useful, thank you.

PPS. This is my first post so please excuse my formatting if it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issues start with following a rather old Whitepaper as a guide, rather than [the more recent documentation](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRdb2RDFViewsGeneration).  I encourage you to follow up on the latter through the channels above.

Answer (score 4):

This may be too broad, as you've asked a few different questions, and haven't really provided enough information to give us a clear picture of exactly what you're trying to do.  That said…

> #### Question 1:
>
> So this is just a fragment but my question here is how do I express
>   that the "Publication" is a class of an existing ontology? As you can
>   see above I am defining from zero the class "Publication".

If you're doing this in plain RDF (not using OWL, or some other ontology language), you just use the URI of the Publication class from the ontology.  E.g., if you're describing some resource `http://.../pub73` from your data, and the publication class in some ontology is `http://publication-ontology/Publication`, you just say:

```
<http://.../pub73> rdf:type <http://publication-ontology/Publication>
```

If you're creating an OWL ontology, then you also should include the `owl:imports` statement to state that you're importing `http://publication-ontology/` (or whatever the ontology IRI of that ontology is) so that you get all the appropriate declaration axioms.

> #### Question 2(more important):
>
> As you can see in the tutorial, somehow the tables that were imported
>   in the virtuoso tool were mapped to a specific URL. However, I wasn't
>   able to find the URL to each table that I imported to virtuoso and I
>   just put some placeholder URLs (These are the localhost URLs). How can
>   i find out the URL to each of the tables that I imported to virtuoso?

Note that the tutorial includes a section:

> ### Key Steps
>
> Based on the mapping process outlined above, some of the key
>   requirements identified are:
>
> - Definition of an RDF class IRI for each table
> - Construction of a subject IRI for each primary key column value
> - Construction of a predicate IRI for each non-key column

I'm not particularly familiar with Virtuoso, but isn't the process of this described in the later section of that tutorial,  **Creating IRIs From Primary Keys** and **Quad Map Patterns & Quad Storage**? That said, it looks like they start by showing the *intended* data model in the first figure (the directed graph), and then *write* some RDFS to describe it, which includes class declarations, e.g., (listing 1):

```
prd:Product a rdfs:Class ;
  rdfs:label "Product" ;
  rdfs:comment "An OpenLink product" .
```

Then later on, they define in Listing 5 a mapping that defines how you'd start to get instances of this class from the automated mapping:

```
graph <http://localhost:8890/rdfv_demo/testdata/products#>
subject prd:product_iri(OPLWEB.DBA.PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID)
predicate rdf:type
object prd:Product
```

That uses the `prd:product_iri` function that was defined in Listing 3:

```
sparql

prefix prd: <http://localhost:8890/rdfv_demo/schemas/product#>
create iri class prd:product_iri "http://localhost:8890/rdfv_demo/testdata/products#%s"
    (in product_id varchar not null) .
```

To assert that rows of your data correspond to instances of some other class, you'd just use the URI of that class in the counterpart Listing 5.  E.g., to make things of type `bibo:Document`, you'd do something like:

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix bibo: <…>

graph <…>

subject …
predicate rdf:type
object bibo:Document
```

Comment: as stated in the tutorail i wrote the code about creating the IRIs and the Quad Map Patterns but haven't tested yet (I will). But as you said they define in Listing 5 a mapping and they say "graph <http://localhost:8890/rdfv_demo/testdata/products#>". Is this just a new link that they just make to where they want to save the graph or is it an existing one that I have to find and use for my own tables? Same question goes for the sparql where the iri class is declared.

Comment: Also what I am trying to do with the publication class is by using plain RDF, which can be imported later in virtuoso through the .n3 files, to describe my new class using existing ontologies like bibo,cito,dc and so on. I hope this helps more :/

Comment: I'm not a Virtuoso user, so I haven't used this mapping technique.  The tutorial also says that things may change in the future, so I think you have to take it all with a grain of salt.  That said, it seems like whether it has to be an existing graph, or whether it will create the graph for you should be easy to test.  Try it with a name that doesn't currently name a graph and see if the graph gets created.